# Don't know how to run app.js in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a complete noob at programming but yeah. Like the title said, I don't know how to run an app.js in node (https://github.com/paterson/SpotifyHack/). Installing `npm install async` and `npm install spotify-node-applescript` was easy but I don't know how to run the app.js file. If I try to run it in the node.js command prompt it gives me this error when I use node.exe it just keeps loading. Can someone help me?

```
Line 1. Char 1. Object expected. Error 800A138F
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're double-clicking app.js on Windows, which by default will launch the file with Windows Script Host, which is Microsoft's JavaScript runtime.  It throws an error because it is very unlike node (specifically, WSH doesn't have a `require`).

With node (once it is installed), you have to open a command prompt and run it there.

```
C:\SomeNodeApp> node app.js
```

Your next problem is that the project you're trying to run (SpotifyHack) uses AppleScript, which is specific to Mac OS.  You won't be able to use this project on Windows.

Comment: Ha! Nice catch on the apple script!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Getting thes errors now (http://i.imgur.com/wFlwrDA.png). Isn't any way to run this script on windows?

Comment: No, AppleScript **only** exists on Mac OS X.

Comment: @user2835700 Did you `npm install spotify-node-applescript` in the [same directory or a parent of the directory](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) that has `app.js`? Node will only search so far for required modules.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: It's obviously a node module, but if you take two seconds to look at its source, you'll see it does nothing more than invoking AppleScript files, which will only run on a Mac.

Comment: @josh3736 Ah. Github's currently [having issues](https://status.github.com/). So, couldn't look that far. :)

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski whoops didn't think of that! Now less errors :P (http://i.imgur.com/239WcHX.png) EDIT: so it can't work on windows...

Answer (score 1):

From your CLI (Command Line Interface), try `node app` when you're in the directory with app.js.